# Here maps API in javascript modal window

Tags: javascript, here-api

I'm using HERE maps API in my service. But I have a problem. Maps is not display in my pop-ups. There is maps block is loading, but map canvas not.
There are all config elements is displaying, but map terrain not.

Here my js:

```
$(function () {
    if (!companyID) {
        return;
    }

    var platform = new H.service.Platform({
        'app_id' : [my_here_app_id],
        'app_code' : [my_here_app_code]
    });

    var coordinates = {
        lat: 45,
        lng: 45
    };

    map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
        platform.createDefaultLayers().normal.map, {
            center: coordinates,
            zoom: 15
        });
});
```

This code I'm using in modal window html template. There are no errors. If I used this code without popup, it's working. I tried to use:

```
map.getViewPort().resize();
```

, but it was not help.
Does anybody know, how fix it?

My html:

```
<div class="dialog-window js-edit-field-window" style="width: 780px; margin-left: -400px; margin-top: 50px; display: block;">
<div class="dialog clear-basket">
    <form action="http://local.misteram.com.ua/order/621/update-user-address" class="js-window-form" method="POST">
        <div class="title">Редактирование адрес клиента</div>
        <div class="content"><style>
            .user-address-text-field {
                margin: 0 5px;
            }
        </style>

            <div class="js-user-data-form" data-order-id="621">

                <div id="mapContainer" style="width: 740px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid rgb(27, 198, 227); position: relative; overflow: hidden;"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <input type="submit" value="Сохранить" class="confirm btn js-edit-window-button-submit">
            <div class="edit-field-ajax-loader">
                <img src="http://local.misteram.com.ua/images/checkout_loading.gif">
            </div>
            <input type="button" value="Закрыть" class="close btn js-edit-window-button-cancel js-close-edit-field-window">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="ngdialog-close"></div>
```

Comment: What about the modal window example?

Comment: I edited code .

Comment: The div in the html template for the map has the id = `map_canvas`, but in the javascript code you use id = `mapContainer`?

Comment: It is a mistake in example. I fixed. It will not help:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set timeout on resizing, it seems that view port is not fully initialized at the moment

```js
setTimeout(function () {
    map.getViewPort().resize()
}, 100);
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned that the above code worked outside a modal popup, it is very likely that the code for instantiating the map is called too early, when the HTML of the modal is not yet added to the DOM.

The code for instantiating the map is inside the `$` function, which, assuming you are using jQuery, means that this code will run as soon as the document is ready.
However this event is fired before the user has opened the modal. While the code may be defined in the file of the modal, the `$` function is *invoked* as soon as that file is loaded.

In short:

- make sure to invoke the map instantiation code *after* the container `<div>` element is added to the DOM
- make sure that the id you are using in the line `new H.Map(...)` matches the id in the html of the modal, as user stdob mentioned

Finally, not the cause of this issue but worth mentioning, make sure to add `useHTTPS: true` when you configure the platform object, or the map tiles won't load when you will deploy the app over HTTPS.

Comment: I adde useHTTPS: true, also I added `console.log(document.getElementById('mapContainer'));` before map initialization, it is logging div element in browser console. As I understood it is already rendered on this moment. But map canvas is still not displaying

Comment: It could be some css issue. It possible to add a picture of how the `mapContainer` block is rendered in the popup? If you add the line `var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);`, providing you loaded `mapsjs-ui.js`, do you see some map controls for zooming? Or you only see your own mapContainer block with the 1px border?

Comment: By the way, the call to `map.getViewPort().resize();` which makes the map canvas resize to the container, is typically added in a listener for the window resize event, like the following: `window.addEventListener('resize', function () { map.getViewPort().resize(); });`

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i'm a little late, but I'll answer the question for others

put all your javascript code for the map Instantiation and display in a method
like so

```
function loadMap() {
........
}
```

And then when you would like the map to be displayed that

```
loadMap()
 window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
          // For the Modal
        map.getViewPort().resize(); 
        });
```

Hope this helps